# Ember js: How to pass param when render template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to pass a param like this from template to controller or route.

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="plan">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Truck Number</th>
    <th>Driver Name</th>
    <th>Trip 1</th>
    <th>Trip 2</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   {{#each truck in model}}
   <tr>
    <td>{{truck.truckNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{truck.driverName}}</td>
    <td>{{render "plan.trip" truck.shipments trip=1}}</td>
    <td>{{render "plan.trip" truck.shipments trip=2}}</td>
   </tr>
   {{/each}}
  </tbody>
 </table>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="plan/trip">
 <ul>
  {{#each shipment in tripShipment}}
   <li>{{shipment.routeCode}}</li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
</script>
```

```js
Trp.PlanTripController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    trip: '',
    tripShipment: function() {
        return this.filterBy('trip', this.get('trip'));
    }.property('@each.trip')
});
```

But this this.get('trip') do not work. How can I render this template with trip as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Use query-params with a link-to helper in your template, sort of like this. In this case trip is a bound variable, but you could also put it in quotes to pass a specific value.

```
    {{#each truck in model}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{truck.truckNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{truck.driverName}}</td>
            <td>{{#link-to "trucks" query-params=trip}}trip 1{{/link-to}}</td>
            <td>{{#link-to "trucks" query-params=trip}}trip 2{/link-to}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
```